# Setting and unsetting variables in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of check boxes, jquery menu, auto complete and input boxes. How would you go about setting a variable that will display in a div with the values of everything that is selected, checked or typed?

I have tried

```
    str += data.id;
```

For example. Which works for everything involved, except when changing the selection it just adds on to the end.

```
    $('#txtDesc').html( str );
```

Is what I'm using to place it into the div and using the on select option in jQuery menu to trigger it.

I'm using the

```
    str += checkedValue;
```

When a checkbox is checked but run into the same problem.

I know what I want it to do but I lack the knowledge to do it or even to search for it because I don't think I'm calling it the right thing.

I'm adding a fiddle, however for some reason it isn't working at all in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/tjje63oh/2/

So basically here is what is supposed to happen.

You select a unit, it goes down into the div, then you select a reason, it goes after the unit, then you select a location which goes after the reason.

If you change a unit, it should remove the one you have and replace it with the new one, but still read in order: unit, reason, location

Comment: You'll have to show some HTML.  Hint though, `.val()` gets the `value` of text inputs and select boxes.  Google for `jQuery radio buttons` and that will get you closer.

Comment: *"...setting a variable that will display in a dig with the values of..."* Say what now?

Comment: *"...when changing the selection it just adds on to the end..."* That's what you've **told** it to do. `str += data.id;` (or `str += checkedValue;`) **adds to** `str`, it doesn't *replace* its value. To replace the value in `str`, use `=`, not `+=`.

Comment: Okay,and thank you for bearing with me but if I use = does that not replace everything within that variable? If I check boxes 1 and two, then select item 1 in the menu drop down. Then I make a change to any of those elements how can I make that change reflect inside the div but not lose whatever else has been selected and placed in that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to me it seems like you want to figure out values of things that have changed in the html and display them somewhere in a "dig" which I assume you meant to mean as "div".

You can do stuff like this and attache is a fiddle with other simple examples

```
HTML 

<input type="text" value="0" />

JS

$( "input[type='text']" ).on( "keypress", addValueToStuff );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h13nLr3v/

Comment: I like your fiddle and it is kinda what I am going for, but I notice that when you change an option it just creates a new entry for it instead of replacing the original entry. Is that possible?

Comment: Instead of .append you would instead use .html which basically empties the selected div and replaces it with the value. Exactly how you are doing it in your original post.